# DoubleClick Search API 403 Errors when making request

Tags: google-api

```
private async Task Run()
    {
        //setting up OAuth 2.0 authentication
        ClientSecrets secret = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = <My ID Here>,
            ClientSecret = <My Secret Here>
        };

        UserCredential credentials = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secret, new[] { Scope }, "user", CancellationToken.None);

        //create the service
        service = new DoubleclicksearchService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
            ApplicationName = <My Application Name Here>
        });

        //make request to download keywords; response variable will hold Id of generated report
        Report response = await service.Reports.Request(CreateRequestBody()).ExecuteAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Created Report: ID={0}", response.Id);
    }
```

First time user of the DoubleClick Search API.  The above code is my snippet attempting to make a keyword report request.  Each run however, the service.Reports.Request line throws an exception.  Specifically the error is:

```
"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nForbidden [403]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Forbidden] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]\r\n]\r\n"
```

Any ideas what's going on here?  If I make the call without the ExecuteAsync() part it works fine, but then I can't get at the Id of the submitted report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, it appears ExecuteAsync was the wrong method to use here.  The retrieval of the Report object that contains the ID of the report being generated is not created asynchronously, I believe.  When I changed the last bit of code to

```
//make request to download keywords; response variable will hold Id of report to be generated
var request = service.Reports.Request(CreateRequestBody());
response = request.Execute();
Console.WriteLine("Report being generated.  Report ID: {0}", response.Id);
```

it worked as expected.

Comment: How important is the value of ApplicationName = <My Application Name Here>. and what is it exactly?